# Hokuyo Node Tutorial adapted to Groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The HokuyoNode tutorial seems to have been written for Fuerte, I'm running Groovy (and started learning with it, so have no knowledge of Fuerte)

(I don't have enough karma to publish the link, so I abbreviated it.)
wiki.ros.osuosl.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode

The tutorial seems to work fine until 1.7 where the following fuerte command (??) is given:

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find hokuyo_node`/hokuyo_test.vcg
```

This results in an error:

```
ERROR: the config file '/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/laser_drivers/hokuyo_node/hokuyo_test.vcg' is a vcg file, which is the old rviz config format.
New config files have a .rviz extension and use YAML formatting. The format changed between Fuerte and Groovy. There is not (yet) an automated conversion program.
```

What is the Groovy command equivalent of what is given in the tutorial that I should run on Groovy in order to get the laser scan to show up in rviz as shown in the tutorial ?

PS. I was able to get the Hokuyo Scanner up and it appears to be streaming. I ran

```
rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node
```

It connected and indicates "Streaming Data"

Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75637/hokuyo-node-tutorial-adapted-to-groovy/) by [philglau](https://answers.ros.org/users/6271/philglau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the simplest way is to do it manually. Just run rviz with any config file and put in a LaserScan display. If you are just running the one scanner, there should be only one topic to choose from.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0